# Retrieval Arguments, Power Builder, como funciona?

Tags: powerbuilder

estoy iniciandome en Power Builder y quisiera saber como funciona los "Retrieval Arguments" de los DW...

Al principio pense que solamente llamando del script al "retrieve()" ya se me pasaban los datos de la BD (por ejemplo de un DW FreeForm a un DW Grid), pero hay que aclarar entonces los parametros de la opcion "Retrieval Arguments"??

Answer (score 0):

El "RETRIEVE()" se usa cuando tu Datawindow esta ligado a un procedimiento almacenado y si tu procedimiento espera recibir parametros seria asi
"DATAWINDOW.RETRIEVE(parametro1,parametro2,parametroN)"

Answer (score 0):

la accion retrieve se usa en los datawindows para hacer que recuperen la informacion para la cual se ha elaborado puede ser un procedimiento almacenado o simplemente una consulta SQL, puede tener argumento o no dependiendo de la consulta. Si la consulta del DW no posee argumentos, solo utilizas Retrieve() para recuperar la informacion en el DW pero si has declarado argumentos en el DW debes usar Retrieve(Argumento1, Argumento2, ArgumentoN) dependiendo de cuantos argumentos tengas declarados.

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.